# JAvascript: How to control array length when deleting rows in a for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to remove rows where [i][1] equals 0.
With the code below  I have anerror "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined", besides that, as the length of the object changes at every update, how to handle that in my code? Thank you,

```
var arr = [['USA Canada UK', '0'],['Canada UK Australia', '1'],['UK Australia Japan', '1'],['Australia Japan India', '1'],['Japan India USA', '0'],['India USA Canada', '0'],['Canada UK India', '1'],['UK India UK', '1'],['India UK Australia', '1'],['UK Australia China', '1'],['Australia China Brazil', '1'],['China Brazil France', '1'],['Brazil France Brazil', '0'],['France Brazil France', '0'],['Brazil France Australia', '1']];

function removematch(arr){
for(var i = 0, len = arr.length; i < len; i++) {
   if(arr[i][1] == 0) {
       arr.splice(i, 1)
   }
}
    return arr;
}

console.log(removematch(arr));
```

Comment: People don't usually store the length when they plan to mutate the array. But you can always subtract the `len` and `i` by 1 under that splice method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't cache the original length property with `len`, just use the `arr.length`.

```js
var arr = [['USA Canada UK', '0'],['Canada UK Australia', '1'],['UK Australia Japan', '1'],['Australia Japan India', '1'],['Japan India USA', '0'],['India USA Canada', '0'],['Canada UK India', '1'],['UK India UK', '1'],['India UK Australia', '1'],['UK Australia China', '1'],['Australia China Brazil', '1'],['China Brazil France', '1'],['Brazil France Brazil', '0'],['France Brazil France', '0'],['Brazil France Australia', '1']];

function removematch(arr){
for(var i = 0; i< arr.length; i++) {
   if(arr[i][1] == 0) {
       arr.splice(i, 1)
       i--;
   }
}
    return arr;
}

console.log(removematch(arr));
```

I would rather use `.filter` to remove non matches. Splice is a heavy operation as it needs to reindex after every delete

Comment: This’ll skip the element after the removed one.

Answer (score 4):

There's several possible answers to this.

1) The one that will leave your code as similar as possible is to iterate the other way:

```
for(var i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
```

This way, deleting an element won't affect where the rest of the elements you are about to process are, only the elements you already processed.

2) Another way is to decrement length AND index when you delete (because the next element to process will take the deleted element's slot):

```
arr.splice(i, 1); i--; len--;
```

3) The way that makes the most sense is not to even have a `for` loop, but to use `filter`. This one line does the work of your entire snippet:

```
let newarr = arr.filter(element => element[1] != 0);
```

Answer (score 3):

For this particular problem, I would suggest using `Array.prototype.filter` instead of `Array.prototype.splice`.

```js
var arr = [['USA Canada UK', '0'],['Canada UK Australia', '1'],['UK Australia Japan', '1'],['Australia Japan India', '1'],['Japan India USA', '0'],['India USA Canada', '0'],['Canada UK India', '1'],['UK India UK', '1'],['India UK Australia', '1'],['UK Australia China', '1'],['Australia China Brazil', '1'],['China Brazil France', '1'],['Brazil France Brazil', '0'],['France Brazil France', '0'],['Brazil France Australia', '1']];

function removeMatch(array) {
  return array.filter(function (row) {
    return row[1] !== '0';
  });
}

console.log(removeMatch(arr));
```